# angular --Import sharedModule inside the coreModule without circular dependency

Tags: angular, angular-module

I need access to **sharedModule=>random.component** inside coreModule... Currently, I get circular dependency errors. Should I keep trying to do this or is it inherently wrong?

here is my current app structure

#### app.module.ts

-> Imports: **core.module.ts**

#### core.module.ts

-> Imports: **shared.module.ts** (i think this is causing circular dependency

#### shared.module.ts

- it is imported by whatever feature module needs
- app.module.ts also imports it
- core is importing it because it holds my **log.service.ts**
- can predict there will be other things needed in *core* from *shared*

#### shared.module.ts ===> log.service.ts

- this is in shared because it's not expected to be a singleton
- Tried removing the share import in core and simply importing log.service in the core component but now core won't

if it's wrong for *core* to imports *shared*. How can *core* gain access to things in *shared*

Comment: I'm not seeing a circular reference here. It just goes App => Core => Shared. And App => Shared. Which is fine. Are you sure there are no imports going the other way, e.g. Shared importing Core?

Comment: feature and shared modules do not import core but shared components do use singleton services from core eg `import { GlobalService } from 'meteorite-core';` ... no mention of core was made in shared.module

Comment: *if its wrong for core to imports shared. How can core gain access to things in shared* You can import it wherever you want - unless shared module is not importing that part. YOu will get circular dependency.

Comment: @Omar thats your circularity. Since share is using core - it shouldnt be separated in the first place.

Comment: i see. so core has global.service (singleton) which is needed in almost every shared or feature module. how do i achieve this? @Antoniossss

Comment: Make that service as a separate module. You will be able to include it everywhere then.

Comment: @Antoniossss I can do that. But now i have trouble understanding the purpose of core services if only app.module can use them

Comment: I will update my question to support this answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226214/discussion-between-omar-and-antoniossss).

Comment: There is no point - its just convinient to put them there as whole application will probably use them. If not - separate module.

Answer (score 0):

Since `shared` module imports `main` module but only for one of it services, make that service a separate module. Doing that will allow you to import that particular module(service)anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should not import the sharedModule in the coreModule, this contradict the whole purpose.
CoreModule is where you load components/modules/prodivers etc that you use through out your entire applications and this should ONLY be imported in the appModule.
SharedModule is used in your featureModules.

Also search ( Ctrl+F ) your application for CoreModule, maybe you are also importing it somewhere else.